# ReactDom.render is returning different type than what I need, how to address it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-markdown

Markdown rendering is the primary focus. In addition I need to parse the html which is passed as string as well.

You can assume, `children` is a html passed as string
and `isParseRequired` is passed as true

```
import cx from 'classnames'
import 'github-markdown-css'
import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'
import { FC, ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { CopyToClipboard } from 'react-copy-to-clipboard'
import { BsClipboard } from 'react-icons/bs'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import reactNodeToString from 'react-node-to-string'
import rehypeHighlight from 'rehype-highlight'
import remarkBreaks from 'remark-breaks'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkMath from 'remark-math'
import supersub from 'remark-supersub'
import Tooltip from '../Tooltip'
import './markdown.css'

const Markdown: FC<{ children: string, isParseRequired?: boolean}> = ({ children, isParseRequired = false }) => {
    return ReactDom.render(
      <ReactMarkdown
        remarkPlugins={[remarkMath, supersub, remarkBreaks, remarkGfm]}
        rehypePlugins={[[rehypeHighlight, { detect: true, ignoreMissing: true }]]}
        className={`markdown-body markdown-custom-styles !text-base font-normal`}
        linkTarget="_blank"
        components={{
          a: ({ node, ...props }) => {
            if (!props.title) {
              return <a {...props} />
            }
            return (
              <Tooltip content={props.title}>
                <a {...props} title={undefined} />
              </Tooltip>
            )
          },
          code: ({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) => {
            if (inline) {
                return (
                  <code className={className} {...props}>
                    {children}
                  </code>
                )
            }
            return <CustomCode className={className}>{children}</CustomCode>
          },
        }}
        children={children}/>,
        document.body)
}

export default Markdown
```

Error I am getting is :
`src/app/components/Markdown/index.tsx:48:7 - error TS2322: Type '({ children, isParseRequired }: { children: string; isParseRequired?: boolean | undefined; }) => void | Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{ children: string; isParseRequired?: boolean | undefined; }>'.`

Note: I am using `*.tsx`

PS: Originally posted at https://github.com/orgs/remarkjs/discussions/1188

Comment: What's the goal of using ReactDom.render? Markdown has FC as its type, which would imply it's a component, but there's almost no reason that a component would need to call ReactDom.render inside it. If you want this component to put stuff into a different part of the dom (document.body it looks like), you probably want to use a [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal), not ReactDom.render

Comment: delete ReactDom.render :s and on the app component do <app><Markdown isParseRequired>fffff </Markdown></app> or use   {createPortal(
   <Markdown isParseRequired>fffff </Markdown>,
    document.body
  )}

Comment: @Lapwood Probably you have missed the line "children is a html passed as string". Since `html-react-parser` don't work well with `react-markdown` so I have been trying `React.dom` as suggested in  `react-markdown`'s documentations. If you can parse the html as well as return FC without `React.dom` you are very much welcome.

Comment: @NicholasTower markdown rendering is the primary focus. In addition I need to parse the html which is passed as string as well.

Comment: qck example : 
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";

const markdown = {
    description: "<p>Hello from the other </p>\n<p><strong>side</strong></p>"
  };
 
  return (
    <>
      <ReactMarkdown children={markdown.description} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} />
    </>
  );

not?

Comment: @Lapwood your syntax is correct and infact I see no difference with what I have written. The point is how to make it return `FC` instead.

Comment: @Lapwood [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) docs suggest use of `renderers`. I suppose some configuration at that level is required.

Comment: dont forget the cute fragment <></> wrapper and it return an FC

Comment: u can take a look at this custom library https://github.com/uiwjs/react-markdown-preview/blob/master/core/src/index.tsx and the previews https://uiwjs.github.io/react-markdown-preview/
and if it s solved tell me to write an anser to solve the thread

Comment: @Lapwood it worked, the issue I had was rehypePlugins array it had double `[[]]` but making it single was through error due to the options `{detect: true, ignoreMissing: true}`. I got rid of all the options too make it single `[]`, now it works.

Comment: happy for you i never use this library before looool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ReactDom.render and wrap ReactMarkdown with fragment tag to return FC and use rehype-raw plugin

```
import cx from "classnames";
import "github-markdown-css";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";
import { FC, ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { CopyToClipboard } from "react-copy-to-clipboard";
import { BsClipboard } from "react-icons/bs";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import reactNodeToString from "react-node-to-string";
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight";
import remarkBreaks from "remark-breaks";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import remarkMath from "remark-math";
import supersub from "remark-supersub";
import Tooltip from "../Tooltip";
import "./markdown.css";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw"; 

const Markdown: FC<{ children: string, isParseRequired?: boolean }> = ({
  children,
  isParseRequired = false,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ReactMarkdown
        remarkPlugins={[remarkMath, supersub, remarkBreaks, remarkGfm]}
        rehypePlugins={[
          [rehypeHighlight, { detect: true, ignoreMissing: true }], rehypeRaw
        ]}
        className={`markdown-body markdown-custom-styles !text-base font-normal`}
        linkTarget="_blank"
        components={{
          a: ({ node, ...props }) => {
            if (!props.title) {
              return <a {...props} />;
            }
            return (
              <Tooltip content={props.title}>
                <a {...props} title={undefined} />
              </Tooltip>
            );
          },
          code: ({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) => {
            if (inline) {
              return (
                <code className={className} {...props}>
                  {children}
                </code>
              );
            }
            return <CustomCode className={className}>{children}</CustomCode>;
          },
        }}
        children={children}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Markdown;
```

Comment: I still don't have clarity why the cute thingy is required with `<></>` or without it is the same for me.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 when you ask me **how make it return FC instead**, then i suggest to remove ReactDom.render and add <></> to force the component to return FC like this we can focus on the other error but now if you want you can remove the fragment tag i usually add them to make code cute only and it make life easy if  i need to add anothoer tags next to ReactMarkdown  and you can have to many markdown on the same block <> <ReactMarkdown /> <ReactMarkdown /></>